# jQuery to required double click AND hover for event

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Currently on my order page I have "Order Status: Pending". If the order status needs changed, I wanted to double click the text and a drop down appear.

So, I was going to hide the drop down and on double click show the drop down and hide the text.

My problem is, I wanted it to GO BACK to text if a user DOES NOT select a new item from the drop down... so I figured you would have to double click and hover the element for it to work.

I did this just for testing:

```
    $(".offerStatus").bind('click', function() {
    $(".offerStatus").hover(function(){
        $(".offerStatus").html("YES");
    }, function(){
        $(".offerStatus").html("NO");
    });
});
```

It works, but it only shows once you click and hover AWAY from the element and then hover back. So, if I click .offerStatus and since I am hovering it, I should see "YES" but I do not. Then when I move my cursor from the element I should see it go to "NO" which works properly. The only thing I am trying to figure out is getting the element to go back once a user clicks away or something of the sort.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you can use keep hover status in element

```
$(".offerStatus").hover(function(){
    $(".offerStatus").data('isHover', true);
}, function(){
    $(".offerStatus").data('isHover', false);
});

$(".offerStatus").click(function() {
    var status = 'NO';
    if($(this).data('isHover')) {
        status = 'YES';
    }
    $(this).html(status);
});
```